# How to convert every first letter in a string of words to upper case with a map?

Tags: haskell, filter

For example I have the String "Hello what a nice day" it is supposed to convert to this: "Hello What A Nice Day".

I want to convert it with a map.

I have tried:

```
upperFirst list = map (\a -> toUpper a) . filter(\(x:sx:xs) -> isSpace x && isLower sx) list
```

This way I wanna check, if my current char is " " and the char behind it is in lower case.
But obviously it doesn't work.

Maybe someone can help me and explain it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`words :: String -> [String]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) and [**`unwords :: [String] -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unwords) to split a string into a list of strings and transfer it back. Then you only need to convert each individual word, so:

```
upperFirst :: String -> String
upperFirst = unwords. … . words
```

where I leave the `…`-part as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you. I think this: ```upperFirst list = (unwords . map(\(x:xs) -> (toUpper x):xs) . words) list ``` is what you mean.
But why is the composition order important? Why can't I swap words and unwords?

Comment: `a . b` is short for `\x -> a (b x)`, so it *first* applies `b`, then `a`, so composition works right-to-left.

Comment: It's worth noting that `unwords . words` is *not* an identity and will sometimes change the spacing, for example if there are two spaces in a row or leading / trailing spaces.  That might be ok for OP, but maybe not.